# How to Select and display latest date (openCobol)

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Im new to Cobol.

A column of Date need to identify the latest date to be display.

8/9/2004

2/7/2016

24/04/1995

27/09/2016

And it able to identify 27/09/2016 as the latest date

Comment: UNSTRING on "/", into fields subordinate to a group item, in the order year/month/day, numeric fields for the month and day, and then you have something you can easily compare.

Comment: Go it ! Thanks @bi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Answer at last.

- Compare date: if Billdate (latest date), move to report date

  ```
     IF WSAA-BillDate > WSAA-ReportDate
         MOVE WSAA-BillDate to WSAA-ReportDate
     END-IF
  ```